# What does it mean if python eval() took the class instance for the first variable and got second set of variables like this?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to understand the DEKR example from [here](https://github.com/HRNet/DEKR/tree/main).

I'd like to customize the data loading for distributed parallel, which load the dataset like below:

```
dataset = eval(cfg.DATASET.DATASET)(
        cfg,
        cfg.DATASET.TRAIN,
        heatmap_generator,
        offset_generator,
        transforms
    )
```

The cfg.DATASET.DATASET means 'coco_kpt', which is the imported module name of dataset and heatmap_generator and offset_generator are the class instances.

With the original code, the dataset returns with dataset object but I'm very confused what dose eval(1)(2) means and what do (1) and (2) made for?

All kinds of advice would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means `eval(cfg.DATASET.DATASET)` results in a *callable* object, which is being called directly.